# Python loop (very simple) only return the first and last items

Tags: python-3.x, loops

```
for n in (1, 5):
     print(n)
```

this only prints 1 and 5
not the all numbers 1 to 5

It used to return 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. Have no idea what went wrong on this very simple loop lol

How can I make it prints all numbers?
I'm using Wing IDE and python version 3.6

Comment: `for n in range(1, 5+1):
     print(n)`

Comment: This code would never print 5 times. You may have deleted `range`.

Comment: Oh thanks. I haven't used python for a while